# Win 10 - CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey") throws Object does not support this property or method

Tags: windows-10, certificate, activex

Win 7 - IE 11 has 6.1.7600.16385 of this "X509 Enrollment WebClassFactory" ActiveX control.

Win 10 -  IE 11 has 10.0.10240.16384 of this "X509 Enrollment WebClassFactory" ActiveX control.

The below call works well in Windows 7 but shows Object does not support this property or method in Windows 10

.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey")

Below is the relevant part of the code used. Messagebox with the above noted error is shown only in Win 10, not in Win 7

```
<OBJECT id='factory' CLASSID='clsid:884e2049-217d-11da-b2a4-000e7bbb2b09'></OBJECT>

set objRequest = factory.CreateObject("X509Enrollment.CX509PrivateKey")
    If ( err.number <> 0 ) then
             MsgBox(err.Description)
    End If
```

What has changed in Win 10 for this active X control?